# How do I run a function on a specific post in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, post

I have a function in Wordpress that fetches fields and returns a string. The function works fine when called on a current post, but now I need to get the function to run outside of the current post and fetch data from other posts. I am trying:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post'
));

if($posts) {
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        $postid = $post->ID;
        $datafrompost[] = custom_func($postid);
    }
    echo print_r($datafrompost);
}
```

How do I get the function to run a different post?

Below is an example of the sort of function it will be fetching:

```
//[inactivesubjects]
function inactivesubjects_func( $atts ){
$inactivesubjects = get_field('inactive_subjects');
return $inactivesubjects;
}
add_shortcode( 'inactivesubjects', 'inactivesubjects_func' );
```

This function works fine and gets the content in inactive_subjects when it is run in the current post.

////////////////////////////UPDATE///////////////////////////

So following Hobo's advice would i be adding this to the function:

```
//[inactivesubjects]
function inactivesubjects_func( $anact ){
$inactivesubjects = get_field('inactive_subjects', $anact);
return $inactivesubjects;
}
add_shortcode( 'inactivesubjects', 'inactivesubjects_func' );
```

And this to the call

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post'
));

if($posts) {
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
      $datafrompost[] = inactivesubjects_func($anact);
    }
    echo print_r($datafrompost);
}
```

But it isn't specifying a post?

////////////////////UPDATE 2//////////////////////

What really confuses me is this will work

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post'
));

if($posts) {
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {

     $string = get_field('inactive_subjects', $post->ID);
    }
    echo print_r($string);
}
```

why cant I use the inactivesubjects_func() in the foreach? (note the inactivesubjects_func() is an example the actual function I am trying to run on other posts is rather large)

Comment: your `if statement` should say ` if ( $posts ) `. You forgot the last s.

Comment: Sorry that was me typing into stackoverflow. The code I am using does have $posts

Comment: I am pretty sure custom_func($postid) is wrong. I want the function to run on all posts and bring back the functions returned string from all the posts.

Comment: add the function to your post so we can see what it is doing.

Comment: The function is rather large. It is fetching a custom field from the post and return the field in some text - the function works fine in a current post when called as a shorcode.

Comment: take a look here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I am still unsure how to get the function tp fetch from other posts. putting the whole function in the foreach would work but it seems a little heavy.

Comment: when and how you want to execute the function ?

Comment: Does your `get_field` call specify a post id?  Looking at the code, it should use the post id passed into your function as the second parameter

Comment: The get_field function is part of the plugin Advanced Custom Fields and it gets the content without any problems. The function works fine if I run it on a current post so surely there is a way to get it to fetch data from other posts. So the function gets data from a posts custom field and returns it. I want the function to get the data from a different post/multiple posts and return it. Thanks a lot for all the help

Comment: There _is_ a way - pass the post id as the second argument to the `get_field` function.  It uses the current post by default, but you can pass a post ID.  That's what I meant.  See [the documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/)

Comment: I have updating the question with your suggestion but I am still unclear how this would run the function on a post->ID?

Comment: You don't need to change the calling function - it was OK as `$datafrompost[] = inactivesubjects_func($post->ID);`.  Though you won't be able to use `inactivesubjects_func` as a shortcode without changes - the shortcode functions won't pass the post ID as an argument.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it just wont work. I would have thought this be simple. Thanks everyone who had a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not following what I'm saying - you're changing more than I said you should (perhaps comments are too short to allow me to explain clearly).  Based on your first edit, this should work.

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post'
));

if($posts) {
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
      $datafrompost[] = inactivesubjects_func($post->ID);
    }
    echo print_r($datafrompost);
}

function inactivesubjects_func( $anact){
    $inactivesubjects = get_field('inactive_subjects', $anact);
    return $inactivesubjects;
}
```

You'll have a problem if you want to use `inactivesubjects_func` as a shortcode, because of the way WordPress passes shortcode arguments, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Cor that totally worked. Thank you for ending that nightmare!

Comment: No worries; glad we got there.

Comment: Cool.  It'll probably stop working if you want to use parameters in the shortcode itself (eg `[inactivesubjects parameter="example"]`), but if you're not going to do that, you may be ok.